# How can I add a datetime field for groups that don't have a time component themselves?

Tags: python, datetime, time-series

Hello I've seen posts similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39877184/insert-missing-weekdays-in-pandas-dataframe-and-fill-them-with-nan) which describe how users can add missing values to a time series using Python. I currently have a list of services with no time component that I'd like to create a row per day for.

Currently the data looks like 
Service1
Service2

And I'd like it to look like:
Service1  2017-01-01
....
Service1  2017-12-31
Service2  2017-01-01
....
Service2  2017-12-31

Comment: How do you know what date to use?

Comment: I would be joining to another table to get the counts per day so I guess I could retrofit the linked answer. Do you know how/if the solution posted would work on groups? All the solutions I found look like they apply to a single series rather than a multiple series for multiple groups.

Comment: Each service also has a child service that I want to capture. I need the missing dates in case the child service has a count on a 0 day for the parent.