# How to get NaN values when inserting missing weekdays into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to insert missing weekdays into a Pandas time series dataframe. The inserted weekdays must have `NaN` values in every data column. When I tried the answers in [Insert missing weekdays in pandas dataframe and fill them with NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39877184/insert-missing-weekdays-in-pandas-dataframe-and-fill-them-with-nan), the new rows are filled with `0` instead of `NaN`. To illustrate:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2022-10-06', '2022-10-11'],  # Thursday and Tuesday.
    'num':  [123, 456]
})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('date')
df = df.resample('B').sum()  # Insert Friday and Monday.
```

However, `df` is now:

```
            num
date           
2022-10-06  123
2022-10-07    0
2022-10-10    0
2022-10-11  456
```

Instead of `NaN`, I am getting `0`. How do I get `NaN` instead? This is what I want:

```
            num
date           
2022-10-06  123
2022-10-07  NaN
2022-10-10  NaN
2022-10-11  456
```

(Pandas version 1.3.2, Python version 3.8.10)

Comment: If `num` column is only 0 for the missing cases, one can replace it with `import numpy as np df = df.replace(0, np.nan)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `.asfreq()` instead of `.sum()`:

```
df.resample('B').asfreq()
```

Output:

```
              num
date             
2022-10-06  123.0
2022-10-07    NaN
2022-10-10    NaN
2022-10-11  456.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2022-10-06', '2022-10-11'],  # Thursday and Tuesday.
    'num':  [123, 456]
})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    

df = df.set_index('date')
```

---

Use [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) if unique datetimes:

```
df1 = df.asfreq('B')
print (df1)
              num
date             
2022-10-06  123.0
2022-10-07    NaN
2022-10-10    NaN
2022-10-11  456.0
```

If possible duplicates and need aggregate `sum` add parameter `min_count=1`:

```
df2 = df.resample('B').sum(min_count=1)
print (df2)
              num
date             
2022-10-06  123.0
2022-10-07    NaN
2022-10-10    NaN
2022-10-11  456.0
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2022-10-06', '2022-10-11'] * 2,  # Thursday and Tuesday.
    'num':  [123, 456, 10, 20]
})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
print (df)
        date  num
0 2022-10-06  123
1 2022-10-11  456
2 2022-10-06   10
3 2022-10-11   20

df = df.set_index('date')


df2 = df.resample('B').sum(min_count=1)
print (df2)
              num
date             
2022-10-06  133.0
2022-10-07    NaN
2022-10-10    NaN
2022-10-11  476.0
```

---

```
df1 = df.asfreq('B')
print (df1)
```

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis